# Double sudoku - two-digit numbers, the 1s and 10s places both form Sudokus

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

Using distinct 2-digit numbers from 11-99 that have no zeros, fill in the grid so that the tens digits form a Sudoku and the units digits form a (different) Sudoku.

There might be a mathematical way to solve this problem since I found it in a fun math book.

[image: Sudoku]

Transcription suitable for copying into a spreadsheet:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 19 |  |  | 91 |  |  |  | 83 |
|  |  | 28 | 43 |  |  | 75 |  |  |
|  |  | 63 |  | 84 |  | 98 |  |  |
|  | 72 |  | 99 |  | 85 |  |  |  |
|  | 54 |  |  |  |  |  | 87 |  |
|  |  |  | 51 |  | 14 |  | 25 |  |
|  |  | 74 |  | 69 |  | 47 |  |  |
|  |  | 31 |  |  | 97 | 59 |  |  |
| 49 |  |  |  | 18 |  |  | 93 | 26 |

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Could you specify which "math book" this problem is from? A link, perhaps? We have an attribution policy here required sourcing for all puzzles.

Comment: can the same number appear twice in any part of the grid?

Comment: can the rule break for diagonal ? In other words, should the units & tens adhere to the rules for diagonal `A1 thru I9` and `A9 thru I1`

Answer (score 3):

Nice puzzle!

Here are some instructions (from bitter experience) to those that want to solve this for themself:

1. Make two regular sudoku grids, one for the tens digit, another for the ones digit. Scanning for missing digits is outright impossible when there are other numbers nearby. Copy the data to (and from) the original grid.
2. Make a list containing all the 81 possible two-digit numbers in order. Make sure to cross out every number you use.

I didn't do either, but I really wish I had. Instead I used two masks on the picture, and used eyeball grep to scan for duplicate numbers when their help was required. Let's see how that turned out..

First, let's do sudoku on the tens digits. Already we manage to find a "deadly shape", that is, now we know for certain that the tens digits cannot be solved on their own. Great!

> [image]

Adding pencil marks for squares that only have two candidates should come in handy once we get to the "combine the grids" part that we now know is certainly going to be necessary:

Repeat for the ones digits:

> [image]

Well, that didn't take us too far.

Then, we'll combine the results, and see if some combinations aren't ruled out by the corresponding two-digit number already existing on the grid. What great joy, the 31 resolves *two* squares, and the 26 and 84 help too!

> [image]

Then, do some sudoku based on this new information, and repeat once stuck. 26 comes through another time, this time with 74.

> [image]

One more iteration allows us to solve the ones part completely

> [image]

and the tens grid follows without much difficulty:

> [image]

And then we double check and realise we've made a stupid mistake with the ones digits, and have to undo the next to last step altogether..

> [image]

There seems to have been an error in box seven's middle row that had propagated to all the marked squares. Had I used a proper list of all the two digit numbers, I would have caught my mistake a lot earlier.

Anyway, great puzzle!

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the in-depth explanation!

Comment: While this is a great answer, I am unable to figure out how to get to the initial stages. I tried to look at all the numbers that could potentially be in each cell. There are too many. Your images shows that you cracked it. I am a bit new so trying to learn to recreate your solution. For ex: in the ones, how did you get all the values in col 3.

Comment: @JoeFerndz the first two parts are perfectly regular sudoku solving, and didn't require any advanced techniques. [This page](https://www.conceptispuzzles.com/index.aspx?uri=puzzle/sudoku/techniques) seems to give a fairly decent list of the basic sudoku techniques; I don't think I even had to use the last two listed there.

Comment: Thank You. The link was very helpful. Appreciate it. Now I am able to connect the dots and understand how you did it.

Answer (score -1):

Via [constraint programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming) with 55 [ALLDIFF](https://sofdem.github.io/gccat/gccat/Calldifferent.html) constraints:

> ```
>  55 19 42 77 91 38 24 66 83
>  94 81 28 43 56 62 75 39 17
>  76 37 63 15 84 29 98 52 41
>  33 72 16 99 27 85 61 44 58
>  21 54 95 68 32 46 13 87 79
>  67 48 89 51 73 14 36 25 92
>  88 96 74 22 69 53 47 11 35
>  12 23 31 86 45 97 59 78 64
>  49 65 57 34 18 71 82 93 26
> ```

Comment: I did not think of using programming. Thank you so much for the unique approach to this puzzle!